# SQL JOIN OPENQUERY Assistance

Tags: mysql, sql, linked-server, openquery

Looking for advise on the best way to approach the following

TBL1 (Local SQL DB) where ID = varchar

TBL2 (Remote MYSQL DB) where ID = INT

```
WITH TBL1 as (
SELECT 
     [Results]  as 'ID'
 FROM [DB].[results]
),

TBL2 as (


select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select  ID, Name from DB')

) 

Select  
   TBL1.[ID],

   TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM [DB]
left outer JOIN TBL1 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
```

Tried a couple different methods like CAST/CONVERT, but ending up with either an error like "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12345
' to data type int." or getting all NULLS for TBL2.

Attempted the following:

```
WITH TBL1 as 
( 
SELECT CAST(ISNULL([Results],'0') AS INT) as 'ID' 
FROM [DB].[results] 
), 
TBL2 as ( select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select ID, Name from DB') 
) 

Select TBL1.[ID], TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM TBL1 Left Outer join TB2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
```

This results in  "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12345
' to data type int."

Also Attempted:

```
WITH TBL1 as ( SELECT [Results] as 'ID' FROM [DB].[results] 
), 

TBL2 as ( select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select CONVERT(ID, CHAR) AS ID, Name from DB') 
) 

Select TBL1.[ID], TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM TBL1 Left Outer join TB2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
```

This results in the TBL1.ID values being displayed, but all the TBL2.Name values are NULL

Comment: For example:
==================
WITH TBL1 as (
SELECT 
     [Results]  as 'ID'
 FROM [DB].[results]
),

TBL2 as (


select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select  ID, Name from DB')

) 

Select  
   TBL1.[ID],

   TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM [DB] AS C
left outer JOIN TBL1 ON CAST(TBL1.ID as INT) = TBL2.ID

==================
This resulted in error: "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12345
' to data type int."

Other Example we tried to cast TBL2.ID as varchar and that returned results, however the Name column contained all nulls

Comment: Do not add facts into the comments, update the question text.

Comment: Use `WITH TBL1 as (SELECT CAST([Results] AS INT) as 'ID'`.

Comment: That results in "Conversion failed when converting the varchar value '12345
' to data type int."

Comment: If so check the value - maybe it contains excess spaces of another non-printable chars. PS. Specify local DBMS precisely, including precise version. Also check if `'select CAST(ID AS CHAR), Name from DB'` in OPENQUERY parameter solves.

Comment: .. and replace `FROM [DB] AS C` to `FROM TBL2` in outer query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Appreciate everyone's help. This is what got this working:

```
WITH TBL1 AS (
    SELECT REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '') 
    FROM DB
    WHERE ISNUMERIC(REPLACE(REPLACE(ID, CHAR(13), ''), CHAR(10), '')) = 1

),
TBL2 AS (
    SELECT *
    FROM OpenQuery(
        LINKEDSERVER,
        'SELECT id, name FROM DB'
    )
)
SELECT 
    TBL1.ID
    ,TB2.Name
FROM TBL2
LEFT OUTER JOIN TBL1 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.id
```

Answer (score 0):

Option 1: Try converting the INT to varchar on the MySQL side of the house. Try to do it right in the sql statement you pass in to the LinkedServer.

```
WITH TBL1 as ( SELECT [Results] as 'ID' FROM [DB].[results] 
), 

TBL2 as ( select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select CONVERT(ID, CHAR) AS ID, Name from DB') 
) 

Select TBL1.[ID], TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM TBL1 Left Outer join TB2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
```

The other option is of course the reverse (if you want to join by INT)

```
WITH TBL1 as 
( 
SELECT CAST(ISNULL(TRIM([Results]),'0') AS INT) as 'ID' 
FROM [DB].[results] 
), 
TBL2 as ( select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select ID, Name from DB') 
) 

Select TBL1.[ID], TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM TBL1 Left Outer join TB2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID
```

Comment: So something like the following? 

select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select  CONVERT(ID, CHAR) as ID, Name from DB')

This resulted in the ID returning, but the name column are all nulls

Comment: If you have run this same query independently in MYSQL and it is returning different rows from when you run it via the linkedserver then something is off with the Linked Server driver you used to build the linked server. Perhaps try an ODBC version or a direct version.
I would also run the LinkedServer query in MSSQL by itself first just to be sure this mismatch is actually happening

Comment: Chuma - Can you provide an example?

Comment: Oh just saying, take this query, log in directly into your MYSQL database and run this query: select CONVERT(ID, CHAR) as ID, Name from DB. Verify that the results are different from select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select CONVERT(ID, CHAR) as ID, Name from DB'). If there's a mismatch in result, you know something's wrong with your Linked server driver and you can go from there. If it's the same, your situation should be resolved and you now know you have null name values

Comment: thanks for the reply. I tested on both and can confirm the results are the same.

Comment: Ok cool, you can just join your 2 with statements without casting. I'll add the reverse option in my answer too.

Comment: @ Chuma I think we are getting somewhere. Using your latest update we returned the company name, but now all the ID values are showing NULL

Comment: @Austin4778, converting a not-null INT to CHAR give NULL? And you don't get them as NULL if you don't convert???

Comment: Ha ha. Strange Db you've got there. Anyway look at my final answer. I gave both options for either converting MSSQL IDs to INT or changing MYSQL IDs to CHAR.
See how it goes.

Comment: @Chuma, what if a varchar value is not convertible to an int? and why would you return NULL as 0? 0 is a valid int value. Someone using varchar for ID and trying to convert it to an int might have already be used 0, -1 and other integer values as valid values. BTW your syntax is not right.

Comment: @Cetin Basoz. So that's the mystery of the whole thing. We don't really know what's in that MSSQL Result which becomes the ID field - could be nulls, could be alphanumeric. Anything really. I just put in a check for nulls is all.
At this point, it would be probably safer to do a FULL OUTER JOIN between the 2 tables to see all rows from both tables to see what's what.
So Select TBL1.*, TBL2.*
FROM TBL1 full Outer join TB2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID

Comment: @Chuma, I don't think so. Check my reply. OP does a LEFT join where TBL2 is the left table and you converted that to a RIGHT join putting TBL1 on left.

Comment: Oh he said he was using my query and I thought I did it correctly there TBL1 left join TBL2. Unless you are saying that TBL2 should be first. In any case, without guessing a full outer join should reveal what is actually happening because it exposes the mismatches from both sides and the matches

Comment: @Cetin Basoz. Yeah the more I think about it, you are correct. The TBL2 should have been the first table and if he changed it to right join or flipped it around so it is the first table in the join, it would resolve likely his issue.

Comment: @Chuma took your examples and attempted them. Updated the initial post in this thread with the results from both

Comment: So try option 2 one more time based on a change I just made. If it still errors out, let's stick to option 1 to figure it out. For Option 1 if your MSSQL ID is varchar, make sure you are converting the MYSQL to varchar, if char, char. Next thing is, for that last part of option 1, try Select TBL1.[ID], TBL2.ID as T2ID, TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM TBL1 FULL Outer join TBL2 ON TBL1.ID = TBL2.ID. This is to reveal if there are actually any matches and what the mismatches look like.
Lastly, help me understand what your primary table is - TBL2 left join TBL1 or TBL1 left join TBL2.

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax doesn't look right. Where does the DB C come from? Isn't DB the schema name?

```
WITH TBL1 as (
SELECT 
     [Results]  as ID
 FROM [DB].[results]
),
TBL2 as (
    select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select  ID, Name from DB')
) 

Select  
   TBL1.[ID],
   TBL2.[NAME] 
FROM TBL2 left outer JOIN TBL1 ON try_cast(TBL1.ID as int) = TBL2.ID;
```

Comment: `try_cast` will give FALSE, and again *getting all NULLS for TBL2*

Comment: @Akina, what do you mean? try_cast doesn't return a value of FALSE, it would return NULL if cast is unsuccessful. In MS SQL server there isn't FALSE anyway (probably you meant 0 though).

Comment: I tried that and it doesn't error out. It will return the TBL1.ID fields, but the TBL2.Name fields are all null

Comment: @Austin4778, you said you are getting NULLs for name???? Are you sure your [NAME] values already doesn't contain all NULLs?

Comment: Correct. I confirmed there are no NULLS in the source MYSQL DB

Comment: @Austin4778, No, you are not really confirming. Does your openquery() return non-null values if you execute all by itself? You are not giving any sample data that fails. If there is say a varchar value of '1' on the MS SQL table, and 1 on MySQL side try select * from openquery(LINKEDSERVER,'select  ID, Name from DB where ID  = 1') to see what it returns.

Comment: @CetinBasoz I confirmed running the OPENQUERY and confirmed it did not have any null values. I ran your query and it did not return any results

Comment: *try_cast doesn't return a value of FALSE, it would return NULL if cast is unsuccessful* NULL in WHERE is treated as FALSE. So according row won't be returned.

Comment: @Akina, I don't understand what you are trying to say at all. NULL is not FALSE. If a value is not convertible to an INT then naturally a join attempt to a not NULL INT should fail. That is desired behavior.

Comment: @Austin4778, where is the sample data? You are saying you confirmed but I doubt. You are doing a LEFT join and still saying you are getting NULL values for the LEFT table. I doubt you are executing something different. If it is the case really, then on matching rows NAME is null.

Comment: I updated the original post with the additional attempts made in the query as well as the results

Comment: @Austin4778, your updated queries doesn't look like the original ones, nor I would suggest querying like that casting to char. Check my reply. Casting to int is better.